# Problemas con el DOM y el traspaso de datos que se me pone todo en una caja

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy trabajando en hacer un texto dinámico que aparezca y desaparezca cuando se aprieta un botón correspondiente.

Con eso dicho y sé que estoy haciendo muchas malas prácticas y pido perdón. Pero, no sé de qué otra forma resolverlo e hice un `array` con los datos (a no tener base de datos externa) y que todo sea llamado por funciones particulares.

El tema es que no sé por qué esas funciones se pone todas en el mismo `div` y no pasa al otro, a menos que se haga clic de abajo para arriba.

Mi pregunta es, ¿si saben cuál es el problema de esto?, y si saben cómo hacer para que después lo que está dentro de la caja del `div` se vaya con el mismo botón, como si removieras un hijo.

Además, si alguien sabe cómo hacer que esto se haga bien, o sea, que en lugar de usar dos (02) funciones que dicen lo mismo, que todo esté en una y que elija entre cada `getElement` distinto sería genial.

```js
let datosInicio = [
  `hola soy texto 1`,
  `hola soy texto 2`
];

var marco = document.getElementById("marcoAle");

const creartextoA = () => {
  let texto1 = document.createElement("p");
  texto1.setAttribute("id", "textoParrafo");
  marco.appendChild(texto1);

  let parrafoDOM = document.getElementById("textoParrafo");
  parrafoDOM.innerHTML = datosInicio[0];
};

/* Ejemplo 2 */
var xforce = document.getElementById("marcoAle1");

const creartextoA1 = () => {
  let texto1 = document.createElement("p");
  texto1.setAttribute("id", "textoParrafo");
  xforce.appendChild(texto1);

  let parrafoDOM1 = document.getElementById("textoParrafo");
  parrafoDOM1.innerHTML = datosInicio[1];
};
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>ejemplo1</h1>
   <div id="marcoAle"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button" onclick='creartextoA()'>
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <h1>ejemplo2</h1>
   <div id="marcoAle1"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button" onclick='creartextoA1()'>
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Aparte, si alguien sabe cómo hacer que esto se haga bien, o sea, que en lugar de usar dos (02) funciones que dicen lo mismo, que todo esté en una y que elija entre cada `getElement` distinto. Seria genial.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiar tu JS, por esto:

```js
let datosInicio=[`hola soy texto 1`,
`hola soy texto 2`
]


var marco=document.getElementById("marcoAle");

const creartextoA = () =>{
let texto1=document.createElement("p");
texto1.setAttribute("id","textoParrafo");
marco.appendChild(texto1);


let parrafoDOM = document.getElementById("textoParrafo");
parrafoDOM.innerHTML = datosInicio[0];
} 

/* Ejemplo 2 */
var xforce=document.getElementById("marcoAle1");

const creartextoA1 = () =>{
let texto2=document.createElement("p");
texto2.setAttribute("id","textoParrafo2");
xforce.appendChild(texto2);


let parrafoDOM1 = document.getElementById("textoParrafo2");
parrafoDOM1.innerHTML = datosInicio[1];
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>ejemplo1</h1>
   <div id="marcoAle"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button" onclick='creartextoA()'>
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <h1>ejemplo2</h1>
   <div id="marcoAle1"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button" onclick='creartextoA1()'>
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Las respuestas con código sin explicación no suelen ser bien recibidas. Además, lo ideal sería no duplicar código, se puede lograr que una sola función verifique el origen del clic y mostrar el contenido en el elemento que corresponda.

Comment: hola Francisco antes que nada gracias por poner código y aviso que lo hiciste funciona pero cabe aclara que estuve buscando el cambio.
al final encontré que lo que haces es cambar la ID de los p que creo.

ahora Triby vs mencionaste que se puede hacer que una función verifique el click eso como se haría? porque m gustaría tener una función única en mi codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Se necesitan hacer algunos cambios:

1. Hay que asignar clase a cada contenedor *principal* para poder identificarlo
2. Asigna clase en lugar de ID a los contenedores que se deben actualizar y a los enlaces
3. Busca todos los enlaces por su clase (la del span que contiene el texto) para evitar más funciones que detecten dónde se realizó el clic
4. Recorre los enlaces para asignar evento, llamando a una sola función
5. Dentro de la función se obtienen todos los datos necesarios para agregar el texto, si es que no se hizo previamente

```js
let datosInicio = [
    'Hola soy texto 1',
    'Hola soy texto 2',
    'Hola soy texto 3'
];

// e es el evento
const crearTexto = (e) => {
    // e.target es el elemento que recibió clic
    // Con closest() se puede acceder al contenedor principal
    // Desde ahí se puede seleccionar marcoAle por clase
    let marco = e.target.closest('div.marcos').querySelector('.marcoAle');
    // Verificar que no se haya creado un párrafo previamente
    if(!marco.hasChildNodes()) {
        // Crear párrafo
        let parrafo = document.createElement('p');
        // Obtener posición del enlace
        let num = Array.from(links).indexOf(e.target);
        // Asignar contenido
        parrafo.innerHTML = datosInicio[num];
        marco.appendChild(parrafo);
    } else {
        // Esto no es necesario, está aquí solo para comprobar que haya duplicados
        console.log('Ya se había agregado un párrafo a este marco.');
    }
} 

// Obtener enlaces dentro de div.marcoAle por clase
// Se usa la del span porque es el que va a disparar el evento
let links = document.querySelectorAll('div.elementor-button-wrapper span.elementor-button-text');
// Recorrer para asignar evento
links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', crearTexto));
```

```html
<div class="marcos">
   <h1>ejemplo1</h1>
   <div class="marcoAle"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button">
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="marcos">
   <h1>ejemplo2</h1>
   <div class="marcoAle"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button">
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="marcos">
   <h1>ejemplo2</h1>
   <div class="marcoAle"></div>
   <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button">
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"
         style="color: #469FED;font-size: 26px;">
      <span class="elementor-button-text">Ver más</span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bien sos un genio de la Vida lo sabias no.
onda desde ya muchas gracias mañana lo veo

Comment: holaTriby desde ya muchas gracias en la vercion de prueba que tengo en la compu funcio genial haciendo los cambios pertinente poniendo las nuevas clases (que era los Id y demas cosas) el caso es que ahora estoy trabajando con el constructor que pe pidieron en el trabajo para hacer el proyecto. Ahi las etiquetas de html del boton y el div están separados. por ahora lo dejo junto.

Tambien te quería preguntar si sabes como hacer que el boton "ver mas" e haga un Ver menos y eso hace que el texto no se vea.
desde ya muchas gracias por todo y saludos.